# How to save state of collapsed children rows (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm trying to make a collapsable table for a project, and so far I'm succeeding pretty well. I'm only encountering one problem that I can't figure how to manage : Actually my collapsable rows (the ones which have children) are collapsing, but if I collapse a child, then the parent, and then I expand the parent, the children is expanded as well. How can I save the state of the children so that they don't expand when we expand the parent?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

// Define color depending on the M1 cell value //
    var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
        [0].getElementsByTagName("tr");

    // loops through each row
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');

        if (cells[2].innerHTML == '1')
            $(cells).parent().addClass('Titre_1');

        if (cells[2].innerHTML == '2')
            $(cells).parent().addClass('Titre_2');  

        if (cells[2].innerHTML == '3')
            $(cells).parent().addClass('Titre_3');

        if (cells[2].innerHTML == '4')
            $(cells).parent().addClass('Titre_4'); 

        if (cells[2].innerHTML == '5')
            $(cells).parent().addClass('Titre_5');

        if (cells[2].innerHTML == '6')
            $(cells).parent().addClass('Titre_6'); 

        if (cells[2].innerHTML == '7')
            $(cells).parent().addClass('Titre_7');

        if (cells[2].innerHTML == '8')
            $(cells).parent().addClass('Titre_8');   

        if (cells[2].innerHTML == '9')
            $(cells).parent().addClass('Titre_9');     
    }

// Expand/collapse when clicking on first column //
    function getChildren($row) {
        var children = [], level = $row.attr('data-level');
        while($row.next().attr('data-level') > level) {
            children.push($row.next());
            $row = $row.next();
        }            
        return children;
    }   

    $('.colex').on('click', function() {

        var action;
        if($(this).parent('.parent').hasClass('collapsed')) {
            $(this).parent('.parent').removeClass('collapsed');
            $(this).text('-');
            action = 'show';
        } else {
            $(this).parent('.parent').addClass('collapsed');
            $(this).text('+');
           action = 'hide';
        }
            
        var children = getChildren($(this).parent('.parent'));
        $.each(children, function() {
            if(action == "show") {
                $(this).removeClass('collapsed').show();
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('collapsed').hide();
                if($(this).children('.colex').text() == '+') { // Replace possible '+' by a '-' when parent's collapsed //
                    $(this).children('.colex').text('-');
                }
            }
        });
    })
})
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

body * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /*color: #59547c;*/
    margin: 0;
}

main {
/*  max-width: 60rem;*/
    margin: 1px auto;
    padding: 1rem;
}

h1 {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

p {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

input.variante[type=checkbox] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}

input.variante[type=checkbox] {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

input.variante[type="checkbox"]:checked
{
  background: orange;
&:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: '\f00c';
    display: block;
    color: grey;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: absolute;
  }
}

table {
  empty-cells: show;
}

th {
    text-align:center;
    border: 1px solid antiquewhite;
}

.parent > .colex {
    color:  black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.table_header {
    background-color:#484e82;
    color:#fdfdff;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.intro {
    font-size: 1.125rem;
}

.Titre_1 {
    color: red;
}

.Titre_2 {
    color: purple;
}

.Titre_3 {
    color: fuchsia;
}

.Titre_4 {
    color: green;
}

.Titre_5 {
    color: lime;
}

.Titre_6 {
    color: navy;
}

.Titre_7 {
    color: blue;
}

.Titre_8 {
    color: aqua;
}

.Titre_9 {
    color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Devis</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <intro>
        <p class="intro">description</p>
    </intro>
    <main>
        <table id="mytable" align=center rules=groups frame=box hborder=0 cellspacing=1 cellpadding=4 vborder=1>
            <thead class="table_header">
                <th id="colex" width=2%>Co<br/>Ex</th>
                <th id="h_M8" width=2%>V<br/>M8</th>
                <th id="h_M1" width=2%>cd<br/>M1</th>
                <th id="h_M2" width=5%>N°<br/>M2</th>
                <th id="h_M4" width=23%>Désignation<br/>M4</th>
                <th id="h_M7" width=3%>Uté<br/>M7</th>
                <th id="h_M9" width=3%>Qté <br/>M9</th>
                <th id="h_M18" width=5%>PR Fourniture unitaire<br/>M18</th>
                <th id="h_M20" width=3%>Type FO<br/>M20</th>
                <th id="h_M14" width=3%>K Acc<br/>M14</th>
                <th id="h_M19" width=6%>PR Total fourniture<br/>M19</th>
                <th id="h_M23" width=5%>Tps pose unitaire<br/>M23</th>
                <th id="h_M26" width=3%>Type MO<br/>M26</th>
                <th id="h_M22" width=3%>K Pose<br/>M22</th>
                <th id="h_M42" width=5%>Tps pose total<br/>M42</th>
                <th id="h_M40" width=5%>PR unitaire<br/>M40</th>
                <th id="h_M41" width=5%>PR Total<br/>M41</th>
                <th id="h_M27" width=3%>qte vendue<br/>M27</th>
                <th id="h_M32" width=5%>PV unitaire<br/>M32</th>
                <th id="h_M44" width=6%>PV Total<br/>M44</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="parent" data-level="0">
                    <td headers="colex" class="colex">-</td>
                    <td headers="h_M8"><input class="variante" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M1">1</td>
                    <td headers="h_M2">A</td>
                    <td headers="h_M4">Titre 1, n'appartient à personne</td>
                    <td headers="h_M7">ens</td>
                    <td headers="h_M9">1</td>
                    <td headers="h_M18"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M20"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M14"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M19"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M23"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M26"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M22"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M42"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M40"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M41"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M27"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M32"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M44"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="parent" data-level="1">
                    <td headers="colex" class="colex">-</td>
                    <td headers="h_M8"><input class="variante" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M1">2</td>
                    <td headers="h_M2">A.1</td>
                    <td headers="h_M4">Titre 2 - la ligne doit appartenir au titre niveau 1, N°A ci-dessus</td>
                    <td headers="h_M7">ens</td>
                    <td headers="h_M9">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="child" data-level="2">
                    <td headers="colex" class="colex"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M8"><input class="variante" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M1">9</td>
                    <td headers="h_M2"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M4">cette ligne "terminale" doit appartenir au titre niveau 2, N°A.1 ci-dessus</td>
                    <td headers="h_M7">km</td>
                    <td headers="h_M9">6</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="child" data-level="2">
                    <td headers="colex" class="colex"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M8"><input class="variante" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M1">9</td>
                    <td headers="h_M2"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M4">cette ligne doit aussi appartenir au titre niveau 2, N°A.1 ci-dessus</td>
                    <td headers="h_M7">m</td>
                    <td headers="h_M9">10,5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="parent" data-level="0">
                    <td headers="colex" class="colex">-</td>
                    <td headers="h_M8"><input class="variante" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M1">1</td>
                    <td headers="h_M2">B</td>
                    <td headers="h_M4">un autre Titre 1, n'appartient à personne</td>
                    <td headers="h_M7">ens</td>
                    <td headers="h_M9">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="parent" data-level="1">
                    <td headers="colex" class="colex">-</td>
                    <td headers="h_M8"><input class="variante" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M1">2</td>
                    <td headers="h_M2">B.1</td>
                    <td headers="h_M4">Titre 2 - la ligne doit appartenir au titre niveau 1, N°B ci-dessus</td>
                    <td headers="h_M7">ens</td>
                    <td headers="h_M9">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="parent" data-level="2">
                    <td headers="colex" class="colex">-</td>
                    <td headers="h_M8"><input class="variante" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M1">3</td>
                    <td headers="h_M2">B.1.1</td>
                    <td headers="h_M4">Titre 3 - la ligne doit appartenir au titre niveau 2, N°B.1 ci-dessus</td>
                    <td headers="h_M7">ens</td>
                    <td headers="h_M9">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="child" data-level="3">
                    <td headers="colex" class="colex"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M8"><input class="variante" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M1">9</td>
                    <td headers="h_M2"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M4">cette ligne "terminale" doit appartenir au titre niveau 3, N°B.1.1 ci-dessus</td>
                    <td headers="h_M7">kg</td>
                    <td headers="h_M9">2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="child" data-level="3">
                    <td headers="colex" class="colex"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M8"><input class="variante" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M1">9</td>
                    <td headers="h_M2"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M4">cette ligne doit aussi appartenir au titre niveau 3, N°B.1.1 ci-dessus</td>
                    <td headers="h_M7">m</td>
                    <td headers="h_M9">10,5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="child" data-level="2">
                    <td headers="colex" class="colex"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M8"><input class="variante" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td headers="h_M1">3</td>
                    <td headers="h_M2">B.1.2</td>
                    <td headers="h_M4">Titre 3 - la ligne doit appartenir au titre niveau 2, N°B.1 ci-dessus</td>
                    <td headers="h_M7">ens</td>
                    <td headers="h_M9">1</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </main>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="voctor.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

[Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VoctorR/oz6qgc5x/3/)

Comment: Does using `event.stopPropagation()` resolve the issue?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment. Well I've tried and it doesn't seem to work :/ I've tried to use children.stopPropagation() under         $.each(children, function() { if(action == "show") { but it results in one of the children row that disappears.

Comment: `stopPropagation()` applies on Event, not on Element. You should try to write it like so: `$('.colex').on('click', function(event) { event.stopPropagation(); /* the rest of your code here */`. Notice that you'll need to pass the event as an argument to your anonymous function.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. Unfortunately, unless I've done something wrong, this doesn't change anything [link](https://jsfiddle.net/VoctorR/oz6qgc5x/10/). I've also been trying to add some conditions to my code, by checking if the next child is collapsed, and if yes return false to stop the each, but either I made mistake, either it doesn't work :/
If you succeed to make it work on the fiddle, please let me know, I'm in a bit of a struggle there haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood your issue, **you want to be able to open a "parent" without opening its children**.

But then, why did you write your code to do so ?

See the culprit in the code bellow:

```
        var children = getChildren($(this).parent('.parent'));
        $.each(children, function() {
            if(action == "show") {
                /* HERE : This line only purpose is to display the children when a parent is displayed */
                $(this).removeClass('collapsed').show(); // <-- DELETE THIS
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('collapsed').hide();
                if($(this).children('.colex').text() == '+') { // Replace possible '+' by a '-' when parent's collapsed //
                    $(this).children('.colex').text('-');
                }
            }
        });
```

---

**EDIT:**
Since your requirements have changed you need to review your logic.

What we know:

- only parents can be collapsable
- opening parents should only reveal their direct children AND the sub-children that were not previously hidden

To achieve this behavior, we'll need to **make a difference between a collapsed parent AND its hidden children**.

See the changes in the code :

```
var level = $(this).parent('.parent').attr('data-level');
var children = getChildren($(this).parent('.parent'));
$.each(children, function() {
    if(action == "show") {              
        if ($(this).attr('data-level')==parseInt(level)+1 
        || $(this).hasClass('hidden')===false) {
            /* un-hide direct children, and not hidden sub-children */
            $(this).removeClass('hidden').show();
      }
    } else {            
        if ($(this).attr('data-level')==parseInt(level)+1) {
                /* apply hidden to direct children */
                $(this).addClass('hidden');
        }
        /* hide all children */
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

I edited your [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tcaweb49/) with the new code if you want to test it.

I also replaced your multiple `if` statements with a single line :

```
$(cells).parent().addClass('Titre_'+cells[2].innerHTML);
```

Comment: Yes that's what I'm trying to do. To have a hierarchy between each elements. If you collapse a data-level 0, it hides every children depending of it. But if you collapse a child, and then the parent, and then expand this parent, the child shall remain collapsed.
At first, this feature wasn't needed, but now it does. The problem is that I obviously can't manage to find exactly what to change in this code to do what I want now (I started my code with an existing code I found and was perfect at that time).
I don't know if that's clear, I can't find what to change (still new as I said)
Thanks

Comment: @Voctor Simply remove the line `$(this).removeClass('collapsed').show();` then, so it won't force to open the children anymore.

Comment: I tried but if I do so, the if(action == "show") is then useless and nothing happens when I click to expand the row

Comment: @Voctor OK, I think there is another problem. Your condition in getChildren should probably be `>= level`  instead of `>level`. I tried it in yout Fiddle and it seems to work.

Comment: Then there's a problem with me I guess. I did what you say and it doesn't work for me. The only change that happens is that when I collapse the first row (the data-level 0) it collapses everything below, when it before stopped at the next same data level row.
It doesn't seem to stop the collapsed children to expand. If that works for you, I definitely don't know what's happening...

Comment: I've tried to add some logic operators to add some conditions. Something like `if(action == "show" && !$row.next().hasClass('collapsed')` to show, but if the next has 'collapsed' as a class, it returns false to stop the $.each, but either I didn't succeed to put it correctly, either it's not meant to work... Do you think that might the solution if put the right way ?

Comment: @Voctor you are making things more complicated than they should. You need to simply review your logic since the requirements have changed. Give me 5 minutes to edit my answer and post a complete solution.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot ! I obviously couldn't succeed to get out of my own logic and think differently. Thank you very much, that'll help me a lot for my further coding, and it will help me to think in a better way next time I'm stucked !
Have a great day sir